# Account Kit JS mini-fication Issue - Page Speed insights

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, google-pagespeed, account-kit

We are using Facebook Account Kit for Authentication purpose.

On evaluating our website against [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), we found this suggestion:

Minifying https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js could save 650B (57% reduction) after compression.

Kindly Suggest, what to do here?